# "Change type" pulldown in Alfresco Share completely empty

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm working through the "Content Modelling" tutorials for Alfresco 5.0.d:

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-content-models-tutorials-create-custom-content.html

Part of the tutorial is creating a "custom type".

PROBLEM: I'm not able to see *any* "types" in Alfresco Share.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

1. Log on to Alfresco (http://localhost:8080/share)
2. Click on a document I created with the the demo
3. Select "Change Types"
   <= the pulldown is completely empty

This is from the `customModel.xml` file the tutorial instructed us to create:

```
<model name="my:custommodel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
   <imports>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
   ...
   <namespaces>
      <namespace uri="http://www.mycompany.com/model/content/1.0" prefix="my"/>
   ...
   <types>
     <type name="my:doc">   
        <title>MyCompany Generic Document</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
      ...
     <type name="my:marketingDoc">
        <title>MyCompany Marketing Document</title>
        <parent>my:doc</parent>
      ...
     <type name="my:whitepaper">
         <title>MyCompany Whitepaper</title>
         <parent>my:marketingDoc</parent>
      ...
```

Here is a snippet from my configuration file, `$ALFRESCO/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml`:

```
 <config evaluator="model-type" condition="my:whitepaper">
   <forms>
     <form>
       <field-visibility>
         <show id="cm:name" />
         <show id="my:product" />
         ...
 <config evaluator="node-type" condition="my:whitepaper">
   <forms>
     <form>
       <field-visibility>
         <show id="cm:name" />
         <show id="my:product" />
         ...
  <types>
     <type name="cm:content">
        <!-- Custom sub-type added for whitepapers -->
        <subtype name="my:whitepaper" />
        ...

     <type name="cm:folder">
     </type>

     <type name="trx:transferTarget">
        <subtype name="trx:fileTransferTarget" />
     </type>
  </types>
```

SOLUTION:

To make the custom type visible, I needed to edit `$ALFRESCO/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/messages/slingshot.properties`:

```
  ...
# Types
type.cm_content=Content Base Type
type.cm_folder=Folder Base Type
type.trx_transferTarget=Transfer Target
type.trx_fileTransferTarget=File Transfer Target

type.my_doc=Tutorial Doctype
type.my_marketingdoc=Tutorial Marketing Doctype
type.my_whitepaper=Tutorial Whitepaper Doctype
  <= This will make the types visible in the
     "Alfresco Share > My Documents > Change Type" pull-down
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A document you upload will be of type cm:content by default.

If you want to change its type, define your own type in a repository content model, like this:

> ```
> <type name="my:subtype">
>         <title>My subtype</title>
>         <parent>cm:content</parent>
>   </type>
> ```

Then add it as a subtype for cm:content in share-config-custom.xml like this:

> ```
>   <type name="cm:content">
>         <subtype name="my:subtype" />
>     </type>
> ```

Comment: Hi - Thank you for the response, and apologies I didn't better explain in the original post that's exactly what I was trying to do. ANYWAY: the piece I was missing from the tutorial is that apparently I also have to update `slingshot.properties` before I can see the new types in the "share" GUI's "Change Property Type" action.